# Error in first clementine.js app: "error: connect econnrefused 127.0.0.1:27017"

Tags: mongodb, npm

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:

https://github.com/johnstonbl01/clementinejs-fcc#starting-the-app

But it doesn't seem like the mongodb is starting correctly. When I try to run "node server.js" in the project folder, I am getting this error: "error: connect econnrefused 127.0.0.1:27017"

A couple potentially relevant notes:

1) Nowhere in the tutorial does it say that I need to actually START mongodb locally in a separate console window, as I have done in previous mongo practice. Is that right?
2)  I also haven't created a './data' folder as I did with previous mongo practice.

Help?

Comment: run `mongod` in a separate window to start DB

Comment: It would make more sense to raise this as an issue with the project, maybe create a pull request with some updated documentation.